# The SHIPPING AND HANDLING CHARGES section is not showing on the backend?

Tags: magento2, shipping

The SHIPPING AND HANDLING CHARGES section is not showing on the backend while editing the order.
What may be the problem?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seem that you placed **an order** with the **virtual product**. So, there is no `Shipping & Handling Information`.

There is a note: when creating a **configurable product**, the **child products** which are generated automatically they have has **no weigh**t. So, these child products are **virtual products**.

One more thing, we should check if having a custom code which relates order admin template.

My Magento version is 2.2.2.

Comment: I have checked with the simple product also. it's not showing in the Simple product also. And none of the product on the site is a virtual product. What any be the issue?

Comment: Check the table `sales_order`, check your order id in this table, find the column `is_virtual`? What is the value?